# How to re-design Dropdownlist

Tags: html, css, dropdownbox

I have a dropdownlist which is given in the image. I want a cool circle button to open the dropdown & secondly i need the dropdown that gets open after we click the button to be a little bit smaller in Width or maybe i want to redesign it. Is it possible by CSS. Every kind of suggestions are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, put the width of dropdown box as imageWidth - 2*(imageBorderRadius).
You can calculate this width easily as you will be knowing the width and border radius given to the image.